# Best compression algo for random string

Tags: compression, gzip

I have some string like below

```
ff8870fd30db56efd72e8b499a454c4e27be6ab70e23dd59a864563628e998a
```

which is around 2Kbytes I tried to compress but I am not getting good compression ratio

with gz I got only 400 bytes reduction and with defalte I got 450 reduction ..

Is there any better alogoritham to have more compression atleast more than 50% reduction .

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you cannot compress random data because it will not contain any structure you can represent / describe in a more efficient way, using less bits.
If this is possible, the data contains a structure and is no longer random.

A common counter-argument is that, given enough odds, even an all 0 string can be generated by a RNG, but devil is in details: it is all about odds!
Even in a tiny 2KB space you have 2^(2048*8) possible strings if the data is generated by a true RNG or a robust PRNG algorithm seeded with reasonable amount of noise, and the vast majority of those stings will not contain any reasonable amout of "order" you can compress.

The fact you are obtaining a 400 B / 450 B compression on 2 KB is a strong hint the string you are looking at is not really random, just non-human readable or "random-looking".

GZ format is based on Deflate compression algorithm, so it is not clear why the two figures are presented separately - Deflate accepts various parameters for fine tuning compression at the expense of speed, so different settings can justify the different results.

To get better compression on random-looking (but not really random!) data can try with LZMA2 (7-Zip) or even better ZPAQ (http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html).

Answer (score 0):

I do know that this is much later than the OP.... however if you look at HOW the data is being represented then yes it is going to be hard to find repetition as a string... however...

with the example
"ff8870fd30db56efd72e8b499a454c4e27be6ab70e23dd59a864563628e998a" as given...

How else COULD this information be represented? these look to all be HEX couplets.. .for example
"0xff 0x88 0x70" etc... so.....if this was stored in bytes....  you automatically get 100% compression since each character is a single byte in itself...

if We wanted to get very clever we could look at some math where say we could map this data to more easily compressible data.. of course this would only be beneficial for very large data, as the encoding of small amounts of data would likely make it larger...